# Jquery to slide up two elements and slide down one element inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 div elements inside a div, and I want to use jquery to slide up 2 of the elements and slide down 1 of the element at once.

**html**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='div1'></div>
    <div class='div2'></div>
    <div class='div3'></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
}

.div1 {
    background: red;
}

.div2 {
    background: blue;
}

.div3 {
    background: green;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container')
      .children('.div1')
      .slideUp(2000)
      .end()
      .children('.div2')
      .animate({height:0},2000)
      .end()
      .children('.div3')
      .slideUp(2000);
})
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcv71go/)

I want the second(div2) at the middle, the blue colored one to slide to the bottom and the other divs to slide up, I know I can't use slideDown as it is already displayed, I think I have to use animate, but how do I make it to animate to the bottom ?

*The script has to be written in that way, as I am using it inside a setInterval function.

Can somebody help me with the fix to accomplish this ?
All suggestions are welcomed.
Thx in advance

Comment: Do you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcv71go/2/

Comment: Thx for your answer, but nope nope, I want all of the to move at the same time, but the two divs at left and right slide to the top and the div in the middle slide to the bottom, you can see in the JSfiddle I provided above the three of them slide to the top at the same time, what I want is for the middle to slide to the bottom

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcv71go/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you position the divs relatively or absolutely you can animate the top and the height of the middle div simultaneously.

[I have updated your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcv71go/1/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container')
      .children('.div1')
      .slideUp(2000)
      .end()
      .children('.div2')
      .animate({top: 300,height:0},2000)
      .end()
      .children('.div3')
      .slideUp(2000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

.div1 {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
}

.div2 {
    background: blue;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0px;
}

.div3 {
    background: green;
    left: 200px;
}
```